# Incrementar el valor de 2 variables a través de 2 while

Tags: php, while

Quisiera incrementar el valor de 2 variables a través de 2 while donde el valor de la variable i solo pueda aumentar cuando la variable j alcance el fin del ciclo.

a continuación el código del planteamiento

```
$i = 0;
$j = 0;

while ($i <= 2){

    while($j <= 2){

        echo $i.'+'.$j.'<br>';
        $j++;

    }

    $i++;
};
```

el resultado que obtengo con este código es el siguiente:

> 0+0, 0+1, 0+2

sin embargo, lo que busco es algo como esto:

> 0+0, 0+1, 0+2, 1+0, 1+1, 1+2, 2+0, 2+1, 2+2

algún planteamiento que pueda ayudarme?

Comment: Tienes que reiniciar `$j`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo único que haría falta es inicializar `$j` antes del `while`

```
$i = 0;

while ($i <= 2){
    // Inicializar j
    $j = 0;
    while($j <= 2){

        echo $i.'+'.$j.'<br>';
        $j++;

    }

    $i++;
};
```

Esto devuelve:

```
0+0<br>0+1<br>0+2<br>1+0<br>1+1<br>1+2<br>2+0<br>2+1<br>2+2<br>
```

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias por aclarar mi duda